# TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The log indicates the error is in this line in one of my controllers

```
    original_cloudinary = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:original_image],
                                     :public_id => params[:band_name].gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '_')+"-"+params[:shirt_name].gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '_')+"-"+"#{Time.now.to_i}",
                                     :discard_original_filename => true)
```

Any idea as to what is causing this error?

Is this enough info? If you need more, please let let me know what you need. Any help would be very helpful. I'm a hack programmer at best and just feeling my way through this. Thanks!

Comment: I'd *guess* that `params[:original_image]` is `nil`; other things being `nil` would raise a different error ("undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass"). But if you want to be sure, check what `params` contains.

Comment: First tip: split this into multiple lines.  This is very hard to read.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you most likely have a nil in either `params[:band_name]` or `params[:shirt_name]` - you will never be guaranteed to have these present, and you can't call string methods on them when they're nil, so you need to check them first. eg try something like this:

```
# do something better than raising an exception
raise "no band_name" if params[:band_name].blank?
raise "no shirt name" if params[:shirt_name].blank?

# better to put complicated things into variables rather than have a really long unreadable line
band_name = params[:band_name].gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '_')
shirt_name = params[:shirt_name].gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '_')
public_id = "#{band_name}-#{shirt_name}-#{Time.now.to_i}"

original_cloudinary = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:original_image],
                                 :public_id => public_id,
                                 :discard_original_filename => true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I'm now waiting on the one person who was causing this error to test it again. I wasn't able to duplicate the error on my end no matter what I tried - even leaving things blank wouldn't re-create the error. I'm just going by his word and the logs.

Comment: As stated in comments, if you have `nil` in `params[:band_name]` or `params[:shirt_name]` you wouldn't be getting the message OP is getting. However, `params[:original_image]` doesn't get methods invoked on it, and it is conceivable that accessing it by `Cloudinary` raises the OP's error.

Comment: The issue is with `params[:original_image]` apparently . Separating the code into multiple lines helped identify this in the logs so thank you! Although the issue remains. The app uploads images to Cloudinary. `params[:original_image]` is the image file. OP _is_ uploading an image file (It's required in the form, you can't hit Submit otherwise) He said he's tried tons of times in different browsers etc...

Comment: He sent me the image file he's using, it worked for me, The app gets dozens of uploads a day...no issues... I'm at a loss... I came on here in the odd chance it was a code issue but I think it's a network issue on his end or a memory issue in my app. Will keep investigating.